# What is the technical name for the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS datetime format?

Tags: date, format, naming

Does the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS datetime format have a special name? I am writing a function that returns a date in this format and I'm trying to figure out what to call the function.

Comment: Got same dilema now :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't find a source, but in my experience (25 years working as a systems programmer in UNIX environments) this format is referred to colloquially among engineers as *Yoda Time.*

It's not valid ISO 8601 because it uses a space instead of a `T` to separate the date and time parts.

Comment: I like the name. But for 'yoda time' google only finds the current time for a city in Japan and for baby yoda. Do you mean Joda?

Comment: Makes sense, is there any source for reference

Answer (score 3):

It looks a lot like [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but you can never be too sure with time formats.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a variation on the ISO 8601 format. There is more info regarding the format here:

http://dataeducation.com/blog/input-date-formats

Comment: Why is it a variation?

Answer (score 0):

I chose the name `formatToUniversalDate` (since that is what ISO 8601 is essentially doing).