# What is the name of DateTime format Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, datetime

From my experience, the most commonly used DateTime format on the internet is: `Y-m-d H:i:s`
eg. `2020-01-29 17:59:00`

Even though this format is so popular, I have not found any standards behind it, nor even a name.

There are a few similar named formats, but they all include the letter `T` instead of space as separator between date and time portion.

My question is, does this format have a name?
And is there any standard that backs it up?
Or is it just an organically created format that everyone just started using at some point?

Comment: Related: [What is the technical name for the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS datetime format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441468/what-is-the-technical-name-for-the-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-datetime-format)

Comment: Page 7 of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339 is I think what you are after. And the note at the end _NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T". Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by (say) a space character._

Comment: [Microsoft / `.NET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#:~:text=Back%20to%20table-,The%20general%20date%20short%20time%20(%22g%22)%20format%20specifier,of%20a%20specific%20DateTimeFormatInfo%20object.) calls it `General Date Short Time`

Comment: I can't think of _any_ date formats that have a _name_ as such. There are formats that appear in different standards, and can therefore be referred to as such, but that feels like a subtly different question: "Are there any standards that mandate this particular format?" The answer to that may be "yes, hundreds of different application-specific documents specify it", so any one of those documents could be its "name".

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's an organic format first and foremost, even though the date part (`Y-m-d`) an the time part (`H:i:s`) are compliant with [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

`Y-m-d H:i:s` is lacking timezone information however. `date('c')` returns the full ISO-8601 format.

Also, there's `date('r')` which returns the full RFC-2822 format.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php